# Some bug problem from using Gazebo to simulate PX4 models

Tags: px4

I am trying to use gazebo to simulate the PX4 model. I have followed the steps on the official website from PX4. But I keep encountering this issue. When i try to run the instruction " make px4_sitl gz_x500"  the system will tell me that  { error: unknown target 'gz_x500' }
I do not know how to solve it!

i hope that someone could help me to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

As documentation suggests,

> If make px4_sitl gz_x500 gives the error ninja: error: unknown target 'gz_x500' then run make distclean to start from a clean slate, and try running make px4_sitl gz_x500 again.

Answer (score 0):

try this in Terminal
sudo apt-get install gz-garden

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).